# Sending header according to MIME type of the file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-headers, mime-types

Is it possible to configure `.htaccess` file in a way that some specific header will be sent only with files of the given MIME type? More specifically, I want to send `Content-Disposition: attachment` header for `text/html` files leaving other file types unaffected. Names and even extensions of such files are not known a priori since the files are user uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of search, I am unable to find a solution for sending unique headers based on MIME type. But, the closest thing I found is to to send special header based on their file type.

To send a special header for `.etc` extension file use:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:etc)$">
     Header set Content-Disposition: attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Thanks! But shouldn't it be `Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"`?

Comment: I believe the colon should be removed. Also `; filename="fname.ext"` part is unnecesary in this case and `attachment` has to be quoted.

Comment: Oops! The earlier codes were just copy/paste. Now, I had tested this. Quotation is not necessary.